# Displaying multi lines in Material Button Toggle Group

Tags: android-studio

I cannot display the multi lines in a single button, that I wanna do it like this wanted design below:

[image: wanted design]

But it only ends up like this failed design below:

[image: failed design].

But I can't do anything in the android studio, in which I have tried multiple solutions using the `&#10;` or putting this

```xml
<string name="sedentary">Sedentary\n(no exercises)</string>
```

In string values, it doesn't work like I want in the image above. I used the Material Button Toggle Group, because it's the only function that could group the buttons nicely. So, is there any way that I could fix this?